# Managing SecUserSecRole in spring security

Tags: grails, spring-security

I'm incorporating version spring-security-core:2.0-RC5 into an application - having successfully used the s2-quickstart approach. I'm trying to write some admin functionality to be able to create, edit and remove users within the application.

When I try and delete a user instance, in my user controller, I get an error as the associated SecUserSecRole instances, which define the specific roles the user have to be removed prior to deleting the user instance.

So I get the list of SecUserSecRole instances, within the user controller, and try to delete them using the command:

> secUserSecRoleInsance.delete

But I get the error:

> No such property: delete for class: vidplay.SecUserSecRole

I could create a controller for SecUserSecRole but them I remembered that when creating users in the Bootstrap file and adding associated roles in order to create instances for SecUserSecRole I used the command:

> SecUserSecRole.create user1, userRole, true

So presumably the spring security plugin has all these SecUserSecRole actions to be used.

Is this correct or do I need to create a specific SecUserSecRole.delete action in my application or what else shoukd I do?

BTW Note that the beginning of the Bootstrap  I've added the line

> def springSecurityService

I've also put this in my user controller.

Hope someone can advise.

-mike

Comment: `.delete()` you are missing brackets I think. Considering it suggests no such property since according to error message it is assuming you are trying to map an object within `secUserSecRoleInsance.delete` like it was a declared object like id i.e.  `secUserSecRoleInsance.id` hope error makes sense now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

delete is a method, not a property. `delete()` will do what you want.

Comment: Yes that does the trick - a bit confused mind as the line `SecUserSecRole.create user1, userRole, true` exists in the Bootstrap and the line `userMakInstance.delete flush:true` exists below in this action without any brackets. I'm guessing having addiitonal parameters after the method implies that both of these are methods? Thanks for your help.